# hadoop cluster, datanode cannot run and 0 node are excluded

Tags: azure, hadoop, hadoop2

I am creating a multiple nodes(1 master and 3 slaves) cluster in Hadoop in Azure, I think all the settings have been done, but when I run a test file, it encounters the similar problems with others in Stackoverflow, **I have tried their solutions, but,this problem still cannot solve.** Could anyone help me, I have stuck in this problem for a few day

```
 org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /benchmarks/TestDFSIO/io_control/in_file_test_io_0 could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1797)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:846)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:510)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:868)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1886)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2603)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1439)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:444)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:1845)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:710)
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /benchmarks/TestDFSIO/io_control/in_file_test_io_0 could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1797)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:846)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:510)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:868)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1886)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2603)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1439)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:444)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:1845)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:710)


2018-04-13 01:25:24,359 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: Unresolved datanode registration: hostname cannot be resolved (ip=10.0.0.7, hostname=10.0.0.7)
    2018-04-13 01:25:24,359 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 2 on 9000, call Call#3 Retry#0 org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.DatanodeProtocol.registerDatanode from 10.0.0.7:59340
```

I check hadoop-hduser-namenode-master.log and got some errors, it seems that Damenode cannot connect with Namenode.

```
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.DisallowedDatanodeException: Datanode denied communication with namenode because hostname cannot be resolved (ip=10.0.0.7, hostname=10.0.0.7): 
DatanodeRegistration(0.0.0.0:50010, datanodeUuid=5b728ca4-01d0-4540-b216-e31c01024b49, infoPort=50075, infoSecurePort=0, ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-57;cid=CID-e37e460a-966c-4067-8104-393b2c008d4a;nsid=1665807189;c=1523582587978)
```

But I have add all the private key of all slaves to master, and modify /etc/hostname /etc/hosts, I also modify slaves(slave1, slave2, slave3) and masters(master)file in master.

```
#127.0.0.1 localhost
master 10.0.0.4
slave1 10.0.0.5
slave2 10.0.0.6
slave3 10.0.0.7
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

my core-site.xml

```
core-site.xml
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>hdfs://master:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services </name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
<value>master:8025</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
<value>master:8030</value>
</property>
<property>
```

hdfs-site.xml (master use namenode, slaves use datanode)

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>3</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop_data/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
<value>yarn</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

besides, I have checked the status

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            944M     0  944M   0% /dev
tmpfs           191M  3.1M  188M   2% /run
/dev/sda1        30G  2.8G   27G  10% /
tmpfs           954M     0  954M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           954M     0  954M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1       3.9G  8.0M  3.7G   1% /mnt
tmpfs           191M     0  191M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Finally, I use JPS to check each nodes(when start-all.sh):

slave2

```
7175 Jps
```

master

```
11961 Jps
```

they are abnormal. what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your /etc/hosts. It should be:

```
10.0.0.4 master 
10.0.0.5 slave1 
10.0.0.6 slave2
10.0.0.7 slave3
```

Comment: omg, it works, you really save my life, I was misleaded by teacher's slide... the format of /etc/hosts of slide is wrong

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to disable IPv6. Because Apache Hadoop is not currently supported on IPv6 networks. See https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopIPv6

1. Edit /etc/sysctl.conf

   ```
   net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
   net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
   net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
   ```
2. Reload

   ```
   sysctl -p
   ```
3. Check result

   ```
   sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 
   sysctl net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6
   sysctl net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6
   ```
4. Start Hadoop

I just guess. And I am not sure it works. Hope this help.